# Covers of the projective line over Z and arithmetic Grauert-Remmert

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fundamental-group

This question is the two-dimensional analogue of [Etale coverings of certain open subschemes in Spec O_K](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22883/etale-coverings-of-certain-open-subschemes-in-spec-o-k)

There I asked if one could characterize in a way certain covers of $\textrm{Spec} \ O_K$. As Cam Mcleman answered, this is basically done by the Galois group of the maximal extension unramified outside $D$. A covering of $U$ is of the form $O_L[\frac{1}{D}]$, where $L$ is any extension of $K$.

Here I would like to ask the same question, only now for $X=\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}$.

Let $D$ be a normal crossings divisor on $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}$ and let $U$ be the complement of its support.

**Q1**. Is there an "equivalence of categories" as Georges Elencwajg mentions in his answer for the analytic case. (See above link.) Basically, is there an arithmetic Grauert-Remmert theorem?

**Q2**. What is known about the etale fundamental group in this case? Is it "finitely generated"? Has anybody studied the maximal pro-p-quotients of these groups?

**Q3**. The analytic analogue would be to consider the same question for $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{C}} \times  \mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{C}}$.

**Q4** Lars (see above link) mentions a result for $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{Q}}^1$. Is there something similar for $\mathbf{P}^2_{\mathbf{Q}}$?

Comment: I've actually been thinking about similar things. If I have more time later I'll write some more as an answer. Just to nitpick, though, the analytic analogue isn't $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ but $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}}=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}\times\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ (these are birational but not isomorphic).

Comment: Also, it turns out that covers of the arithmetic line don't follow the same behavior one would expect from a Grauert-Remmert type result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Q3: For any scheme $X$ of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ the Riemann-Existence Theorem (See SGA1 XII.5) says that the category of finite étale coverings of $X$ is equivalent to the category of finite covering spaces of the associated analytic space $X^{an}$. This implies that the finite quotients of the topological fundametal group of $X^{an}$ are the same as the finite quotients of the étale fundamental group, and one obtains that the étale fundamental group of $X$ is isomorphic to the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group of $X^{an}$.

Q4: The same short exact sequence that I mentioned in your other question is still valid.

As in your other question, I cannot say anything about the situation over $\mathbb{Z}$ :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a question which is too long to put in a comment box: What exactly do you mean by a simple normal crossings divisor in $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z}$?

Let me recall that an irreducible divisor in $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z}$ consists either of a Galois conjugacy class of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ points of $\mathbb P^1$ (closed up to make a divisor in
$\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z}$ (these are the horizontal divisors), or else one of the closed
fibres $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$ of the map $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z} \to \mathbb Z$ (these are the vertical divosors).

The vertical divisors are mutually disjoint, while the horizontal divisors meet each vertical divisor in a point (if the horizontal divisor is the point
$\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb Q} \cup \{\infty\}$, and the vertical divisor is $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$, then they intersect in the point $\overline{\alpha}$ obtained by specializing $\alpha$ into char. $p$).  Two horizontal divisors, say corresponding to the points $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{\mathbb Q}\cup \infty$, may or may not intersect; they meet in a point lying over the point $p \in $ Spec $\mathbb Z$ if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same specialization to char. $p$, and one can define a multiplicity of intersection, which reflects the precise power of $p$ modulo which they are congruent.

I'm not exactly sure in this arithmetic context what the s.n.c. condition is.

Comment: I think I mixed up the terminology. Sorry. It should just be a divisor with normal crossings. 